# Numerical Inversion of an incomplete beta function expressed as gauss hypergeometric function using Mathematica

Tags: numerics, inverse, special-functions

I am currently working with this hypergeometric function ${_2}F_1$,

$\rho(r)=\frac{2b}{1-q}(1-(\frac{b}{r})^{1-q})^{\frac{1}{2}}{_2}F_1(\frac{1}{2},1-\frac{1}{q-1},\frac{3}{2},1-(\frac{b}{r})^{1-q})$

I have just started learning and using Mathematica and I just want to ask if  I can use Mathematica to construct and implement a simple routine to numerically invert the function $\rho(r)$ into $r(\rho)$? Note that $-\infty<q<1$, and $r,b>0$. Also, at $r=b$, $\rho=0$.

I have already tried the following routine

```
r[\rho_] := r /. Solve[\rho == (b/(1 - q)) (1 - (b/r)^(1 - q))^(1/2)/(1/
     2) Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1 - 1/(q - 1), 1/2 + 1, 
   1 - (b/r)^(1 - q)], r][[1]]
r[1]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you search the documentation?

Comment: I have tried the InverseFunction command but nothing happens.

Comment: Try to put yourself in our position, there is very little we can do without seeing the specific code you have used and an something more information rich than *"nothing happens"*. Please read my first comment and follow the links. Please share the code that defines $\rho(r)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\[Rho][r_, b_, q_] := (2*b/(1 - q))*(1 - (b/r)^(1 - q))^(1/2)*
  Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1 - 1/(q - 1), 3/2, 1 - (b/r)^(1 - q)]
R = InverseFunction[
  Function[{r, b, q}, (2*b/(1 - q))*(1 - (b/r)^(1 - q))^(1/2)*
    Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1 - 1/(q - 1), 3/2, 1 - (b/r)^(1 - q)]], 1,
   3]
{Plot[\[Rho][r, 1, -2], {r, 0, 3}], 
 Plot[R[x, 1, -2], {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: This works. Thank you.